# PySerial on Raspberry-Pi give me [Errno 5] and [Errno 11]

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I'm trying to set up an IR Receiver Breakout (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8554) to my Raspberry Pi. I connected the 'out' on the receiver to the 'RXD' pin on the py and im using PySerial to read the inputs,

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=1)

while True:
    print ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried different timeouts, using readlines instead of read, using read(1) instead of read(inWaiting). Regardless what I try I keep getting one of two errors:

```
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

or

```
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

EDIT: More Info

The program works for a while at first and the errors come a few minutes later.
Not sure if this matter, but just in case, I have tried with different IR remotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the IR receiver, i probably did something wrong and damaged it at some point since i'm a noob. I got a new one and now i no longer get the errors.